# How to Get & build chromium (svn client too old)

Tags: build, chromium

I am trying to get & build chromium on win7 & VS 2010.
I follow http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows
and http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code but no luck.

This document is confusing for me, especially for depot tool.

Can someone guide me step how to get code (i am getting error svn to old - put director in front & in end one by one).

is there some video or better step by step tutorial. I would like direct svn checkout. (if i use cygwin svn its give missing file on compilation)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and managed to fix it by running:

```
gclient runhooks --force
```

The documentation says it should be run inside the src folder but this didn't work for me, running it in the folder that contains the src folder fixed it.

I also found another problem in the "Official/WPO/LTCG build" section of documentation that causes C1083 PCH file not found errors.

To fix this you need to set the chromium_win_pch variable to zero in the ~.gyp\include.gypi (C:\Users\USERNAME\.gyp\include.gypi), like this:

```
{
  'variables': {
    'chromium_win_pch': 0,
  }
}
```